# C# Beginner, How to add Queue int to total int?

Tags: c#, loops, queue

Here is the requirement:

> Please loop through the queue using a while loop, and add the next
>   item to the total variable. After the loop, please write the total to
>   the console using Console.WriteLine.

And here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Queue<int> primes = new Queue<int>();

        primes.Enqueue(2);
        primes.Enqueue(3);
        primes.Enqueue(5);
        primes.Enqueue(7);
        primes.Enqueue(11);

        int total = 0;

        while(primes.Count > 0)
        {
            total += primes.Dequeue();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);
    }
}
```

The tutorial won't accept this answer even though I get an output of 28. I've encountered a bug on this before so I'm not sure if I'm correct or the site's just screwy. Is this right? If not, what am I missing?

https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2047/Pages/20

Comment: Stop using that website, please. It's full of bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, they want you to use "foreach" instead of while. use below code snippet and submit to them

```
    foreach (var Item in primes)
        total += Item;
```

Comment: the directions literally say `use a while loop`